# Create Contract Solidity 0.5

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, arrays, solidity-0.5.x

My code works with compiler 0.4.25 but not with the latest version.
I want to keep track of every "Contract 2" that "Contract 1" create.

Contract 1

```
uint public countContract;
address[] public deployedContracts;

function createContract(string memory _name) 
public{       
    address newContract = new Contract2(countContract++, _name);
    deployedContracts.push(newContract);
 }
```

Contract 2

```
uint public id;
string public name; 

constructor(uint _id, string memory _name) 
public{
    id = _id;
    name = _name;
}
```

The error I am receiving on Remix is:

> browser/temp.sol:9:5: TypeError: Type contract Contract2 is not implicitly convertible to expected type address.
>       address newContract = new Contract2(countContract++, _name);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Solidity 0.5, you need to explicitly store the type of the contract being created (as opposed to simply using the `address` type). Use the following code to achieve your goals:

Contract 1:

```
uint public countContract;
Contract2[] public deployedContracts;

function createContract(string memory _name) 
    public
 {       
    Contract2 newContract = new Contract2(countContract++, _name);
    deployedContracts.push(newContract);
 }
```

Contract 2:

```
uint public id;
string public name; 

constructor(uint _id, string memory _name) 
    public
{
    id = _id;
    name = _name;
}
```

Note: you will still add the address of the contract to the array, just as you were doing in 0.4.